# React useContext returns undefined before requested object resulting in an error when trying to use .map(). How can I get rid of undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't render props from useContext because it returns undefined before desired object. I can't seem to find any solution to my problem.

This is the child element I'm trying to render:

```
const Reviews = ({reviews}) => {
    return (
        <div className={styles['review__card']}>
            {reviews.map((review) => {
                return(
                <div className={styles['review__card__item']}>
                    <div className={styles['card__item__meta']}>
                        <span>{review.name}</span>
                        <span><StarRating rating={review.rating}/></span>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles['card__item__p']}>
                        <p>{review.revew}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                )})}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Reviews
```

This is Parent Element:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { RestaurantsContext } from '../context/RestaurantsContext';
import Wrapper from '../components/Wrapper'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import Reviews from '../components/Reviews'
import AddReview from '../components/AddReview'
import RestaurantFinder from '../apis/RestaurantFinder';

const RestaurantDetailPage = () => {
    const {id} = useParams()
    const {selectedRestaurant, setSelectedRestaurant} = useContext(RestaurantsContext)
    useEffect(()=> {
        const fetchDate = async () => {
            try { 
                const response = await RestaurantFinder.get(`/${id}`)
                setSelectedRestaurant(response.data.data)
            }
            catch (err) {console.log(err)
            }
        }
        fetchDate()
    }, [])

    console.log(selectedRestaurant.reviews)

    return (

        <Wrapper>
            <Header title={ 'RestaurantDetailPage' }/>
            <div>{selectedRestaurant && (
                <>
                    <Reviews reviews={selectedRestaurant.reviews}/>
                    <AddReview/>
                </>
            )}</div>
        </Wrapper>
    )
}

export default RestaurantDetailPage
```

Whenever I console.log(selectedRestaurant.reviews) it gives me undefined and then it gives me object query. I assume that .map() is getting an error because it is trying to render that first argument which is *undefined*

Here is Context js

```
import React, {useState, createContext} from 'react';

export const RestaurantsContext = createContext();

export const RestaurantsContextProvider = props => {
    const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = useState([])
    const [selectedRestaurant, setSelectedRestaurant] = useState([])
    
    const addRestaurants = (restaurant) => {
        setRestaurants([...restaurants, restaurant]);
    }
    return (
        <RestaurantsContext.Provider value={{restaurants, setRestaurants, addRestaurants, selectedRestaurant, setSelectedRestaurant }}>
            {props.children}
        </RestaurantsContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Comment: selectedRestaurant, setSelectedRestaurant need to be defined in the createContext, and to be updated through the provider

Comment: Im sorry im new to react and especially to context. Could you please show me how to define them in createContext.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue and solved it though I'm not entirely sure how it works.

```js
const [selectedRestaurant, setSelectedRestaurant] = useState([])
```

default useState value should be `null` using `useState(null)`